# Is postfix respecting greylist response?

Tags: postfix, greylisting

I"m a bit confused about the activity in my mail server logs (addresses and destination redacted for privacy):

```
Nov  1 21:00:03 mail postfix/smtp[745742]: Trusted TLS connection established to mx.example.com[192.0.2.1]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Nov  1 21:00:10 mail postfix/smtp[745742]: 0C1551DC073: to=<johndoe@example.com>, relay=mx.example.com[192.0.2.1]:25, delay=7.3, delays=0.01/0.01/0.42/6.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7E42A921A9A25)
Nov  1 21:00:11 mail postfix/smtp[745829]: Trusted TLS connection established to mx.example.com[192.0.2.1]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Nov  1 21:00:18 mail postfix/smtp[745829]: 903371DC08B: host mx.example.com[192.0.2.1] said: 451 4.7.1 Greylisting in action, please come back later (in reply to end of DATA command)
Nov  1 21:00:18 mail postfix/smtp[745829]: Trusted TLS connection established to mx.example.net[192.0.2.2]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Nov  1 21:00:25 mail postfix/smtp[745829]: 903371DC08B: to=<janedoe18@example.ca>, relay=mx.example.net[192.0.2.2]:25, delay=16, delays=0.01/1.4/7.7/7.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as BB99F922EC625)
```

It appears  postfix got a greylist response on the second mail to the domain in question but then immediately re-attempted delivery to a different MX record ip (@21:00:18)? Am I misunderstanding what's going on here?

All settings are more or less default with these exceptions:

```
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
maximal_backoff_time = 3h
```

I want to make sure we are respecting the recipient provider's response but it doesn't appear that postfix waited 180 seconds before reattempting delivery as I would have expected.

Comment: You should not use RFC1918 addresses as examples in place of global IP addresses; that _does_ cause confusion. Use the IP address ranges set aside for examples in [RFC 5737](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737) to replace global IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question and learned something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, postfix respects the greylist response.. but not to the letter because it does not read the English status text.**

**Recommendation:** *Probably no need to change anything - the other MX did accept your message merely seconds later.* This game of *"please wait for 10 minutes"* is not played by everyone doing or calling it *greylisting*. You really just need *one* extra connection to prove you operate a mail queue (or do not care to play by the rules anyway), so there is not always a point in letting other mail servers wait for longer than some reputation database lookups take.

**Explanation of the behaviour:**

Postfix does not care what the specific reason was, only that it saw a  **temporary error** *in reply to end of DATA command*.
<sub>The same Status code (451) and Enhanced Status Code (4.7.1) could have been used for many other reasons, and none of them clearly conveys: *"Do not talk to me or my other MX"*.</sub>

Until the message is *deferred* and subject to the `_backoff_time` rules, postfix does keep trying if any **other MX** is ready to accept the message. A mail currently in *active* delivery is automatically moved to the *deferred* queue based on one of the following two condition:

1. all currently known mail exchangers have been tried, and none of them conclusively accepted (e.g. code 250) or permanently rejected (e.g. code 550) the message for the outstanding recipients
2. a threshold (*cohort limit*) of failures have been encountered and further delivery for the destination is deferred

If you want postfix to space out and eventually defer outstanding deliveries after seeing too many deliveries fail, use `_destination_rate_delay` and `_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit` instead.

Comment: Interesting - so are you saying that this particular response code is not telling us the message is deferred and therefore does not trigger the backoff_time rules?  What response code *would* trigger those actions?

Comment: This particular response code begins with a `4`, thus is a temporary error, thus can only trigger the *backoff* rules when all available MX (or all that postfix is allowed to try concurrently) fail to accept or reject the message.